# Can I set my file permission in new GitLab repository?

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

I have a working GitLab system (8.3.4) and my problem is that when new repository is created the permissions are like following:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 nobody crontab    91 Jan 29 11:36 config
-rw-r--r--   1 nobody crontab    73 Jan 29 11:36 description
-rw-r--r--   1 nobody crontab    23 Jan 29 11:36 HEAD
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody crontab    47 Jan 29 11:36 hooks -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody crontab  4096 Jan 29 11:36 hooks.old.1454063797/
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody crontab  4096 Jan 29 11:36 info/
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody crontab  4096 Jan 29 11:36 objects/
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody crontab  4096 Jan 29 11:36 refs/
```

Is there a possibility that I can add write permissions for group via GitLab to have a result similar to what I would achieve with `chmod g+w -R .` ?

If not- is it possible to create a hook that is run when creating this repository of with first (init) commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set following **umask** value for user's bash startup file (~/.bashrc or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile)

```
umask 0002
```

With **umask** value of 0002 group permission for new files will be **rw**.